# Rails 4: Separate model and controller functions with validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, csv, model-view-controller

I am trying to separate some logic from my controller but cannot get it working the way I'd like.  I have a function in my controller that takes a CSV file and enters each row into my `WeighIns` table:

```
# Controller (WeighIn belongs_to User)

def bulk_upload_weigh_ins
    import = WeighIn.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to import_weigh_ins_path, notice: "Weigh Ins Imported Successfully!"
end
```

Then I have the CSV parsing function in my model

```
# WeighIn model    

def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        hashed_row = row.to_hash
        # VALIDATE HERE
        WeighIn.create hashed_row
    end
end
```

but before creating the entry in the WeighIns table, I want to ensure there is a corresponding User for an attribute in the hash, i.e. `User.find_by(scale_id: hashed_row["scale_id"]) != nil` where `scale_id` is part of the row and a column on my `User` table.

**How can I validate this and return a useful error that tells me there is "No User for scale_id: Foo"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in either model or controller. It's a design decision that most developers do on their opinion of reusability: Is user authorization a general purpose of your model? If you'd like to re-use your model, would you want the same authorization scheme?

If you put it into your model, the WeighIn model should have access to the User model or the authorization model. The import function could then return true to signal success.

In the controller, you can implement authorization by using the condition you already pointed out yourself, or more general, with a "before_action" callback that can check authorization before the actual function is called, like

```
before_action :check_authorization, only: [:bulk_upload_weigh_ins]

private
  def check_autorization
    render nothing:true, status: :forbidden unless (autorized_condition)
  end
```

In both cases, you might want to return either a http forbidden response (403) by using "render nothing:true, status: :forbidden" or a more sophisticated html response by rendering a layout with an error message. Here, "the flash" usually comes in, which you could use in your 'WeighIn/bulk_upload_weigh_ins.html.erb" (or haml) template (see [The Flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)).

```
flash[:alert] = "You are wrong!"
```

Now, in your action either do nothing (renders the default template for the action), render a special template or redirect the user (one of these must be done if you use before_action to stop processing).

```
render 'an_error_template'  # in views/controller/an_error_template.html.erb or haml

redirect_to :other_action # sends the browser to another action, flash[:alert] is still accessible there
```

Remember to query the flash in your layout or action template to display messages like

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks you for such a detailed response, I will surely put these steps in place.